# Jquery Hover State

Tags: jquery

I have created a query hover state. When you hover over the small picture it displays the drop down menu. Although it does not stay on the hover state.

Can some show where I am going wrong? I need the dropdown menu to stay showing when hovered on it.

http://jsfiddle.net/tj7cq/1/

```
$(".author-profile-top").hover(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(".dropdown-profile").toggle();
})

 $(".dropdown-profile").click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
})
```

Any help would be great!!!!

Comment: You're not including jquery in your fiddle, and when included it works, do you mean you want to keep the dropdown visible when you leave the image ?

Comment: you fiddle works fine for me

Comment: I gather you want it to stay up until something is clicked? If you only provide one function to hover it calls it once on mouseenter and again on mouseleave. Provide a second empty function to hover and you will get a little closer to your solution. Please clarify the expected behavior of your drop-down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to try

```
var $toggle = $(".dropdown-profile").hover(function(){
    clearTimeout($toggle.data('hideTimer'))
}, function(){
    $toggle.hide();
});
$(".author-profile-top").hover(function (event) {
    clearTimeout($toggle.data('hideTimer'))
    $toggle.show();
}, function(){
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        $toggle.hide();
    }, 200)
    $toggle.data('hideTimer', timer)
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jQZqA/)

Comment: Can you make the drop down hide when you roll off it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".author-profile-top,.dropdown-profile").hover(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(".dropdown-profile").toggle();
})
```

And change your `.dropdown-profile` css from `top:60px` to`top:50px`

Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tj7cq/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately something wrong with your JSFiddle code. But, looks like it will be better to use mouseenter and mouseleave events for such purposes, I've often had problems with hover event.

Comment: .hover includes both mouseenter and mouseout, his fiddle was missing jquery

Comment: Aha! Now I see what you've meant. I will suggest you to use timeout for hiding menu, so the user will be able to mouse over your menu. And once he will mouse over your menu you can just either kill timeout or set some flag that will be checked in timeout handler and will not hide menu.

Comment: I have almost the same idea as vinothini has. [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/ZT73D/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/tj7cq/6/

```
$(".author-profile-top").hover(function (event) {
    $(".dropdown-profile").show();
})

 $(".dropdown-profile").click(function (event) {
      $(".dropdown-profile").hide();
 })
```

Are you trying to achieve this or some else?

Comment: Can you make the drop down hide when you roll off it?

Answer (score 0):

This is just for your understanding,may be in your future codings you can apply like this.

All though you got the correct answer there ,I would tell it is just a fix ,

Because you just hover over one outside element,and your drop down menu is on a different div ,here is your code

```
    /*hovering element*/
 <li> <a href="#"><img src="http://heyfitty.com/demo/img/general/profile-head.png" class="author-profile-top"/></a>  
    </li>

 /*displayed element on hover*/
<div class="dropdown-profile">
        <div class="popout-pointer"></div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="view-profile user-popup-padding">View Profile</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="the-charts">Edit Profile</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="newsfeed">Settings</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="your-messages" class="user-popup-padding-bottom">Logout</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

So how do you except to have the `<div class="dropdown-profile"`> visible when you move away form you  `<a href="#"><img src="http://heyfitty.com/demo/img/general/profile-head.png" class="author-profile-top"/></a>` to the `div`

The standard method is to keep all your elements together in a div like below code  `<div class='content'>`
Try this

### html

```
<div class='content'>
<li> <a href="#"><img src="http://heyfitty.com/demo/img/general/profile-head.png" class="author-profile-top"/></a>

</li>
<div class="dropdown-profile">
    <div class="popout-pointer"></div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="view-profile user-popup-padding">View Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="the-charts">Edit Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="newsfeed">Settings</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="your-messages" class="user-popup-padding-bottom">Logout</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

and in your css keep the position of your child elements as relative to parent element

```
position:relative
```

here is your css

### css

```
li {

    list-style:none;

}

.author-profile-top {

    float:right;

    margin-top: 20px;

}

.dropdown-profile {

    position: relative;  

    background-color: white;

    border: 1px solid #cccccc;

    width: 160px;

    border: solid 1px #cccccc;

    cursor: pointer;

    top: 60px;

    z-index: 9999;

    left: 385px;

    color:#ccccc;

    height:100px;

    display:none;

}
```

and your code

### code

```
$(".content").hover(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(".dropdown-profile").toggle();
    })

     $(".dropdown-profile").click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    })
```

### Working [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/tj7cq/9/)